# Is it possible to control polling intervals with GLFW?

Tags: java, opengl, glfw

I have a slight stutter in my 3D openGL application which I think can be resolved by reducing the amount of keyboard input that is processed.  So, I was wondering if it is possible to set an interval on glfwPollEvents or somehow control when/how often glfwSetKeyCallback accepts key input? (eg. user holds the key down but I only want to process it every x millisecs).  I have tried using a Timer object but that results in an illegalmonitorstate exception.

Comment: `glfwPollEvents` works as fast as you call it. You'll have to pause the process yourself.

Comment: you could implement a method that "remembers" last key pressed, and until released, repeat only the action that it's supposed to provoke... something like `if(pressed a key)doSomething = true; if(released the key)doSomething = false;`

Comment: Using Thread.sleep does seems to make a difference.  I'll just need to design it so it pauses only when scrolling.  If it is directly in the game loop it slows the picking..  Thanks!